# jQuery - preload image inside AJAX success before append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm gonna show you the full code of the function which I use without simplifying it too much, because when I simplify it everything works fine. Here it is:

```
function add(z){
    bildurl = $(z).attr('data-bildurl');
    produktid = $(z).attr('data-produktid');


        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'convert.php',
            async: true,
            data: {produktid: produktid, bildurl: bildurl},
            success: function() {   

                currentid = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 6);


                currentzindex = currentzindex + 1;

                $('#baukasten').append(
                    '<div class=\"drag\" id="' + currentid + '" style=\"display: inline-block; cursor: all-scroll; z-index: ' + currentzindex + '; position: absolute; border: 1px solid #000000;\" onmousedown=\"mach(this);\"><img src=\"png/' + produktid + '.png" class=\"resize\"><img src=\"close.png\" class=\"close\" style=\"width: 16px; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px;\" data-raus=\"' + currentid + '\" onclick=\"raus(this);\"><img src=\"resize.png\" class=\"res\" style=\"width: 18px; position: absolute; bottom: 5px; right: 5px;\" data-res="' + currentid + '"><\/div>'
                ); // here is the problem



                $( ".drag" ).draggable({
                    containment: "#grenze"
                });

                $( ".resize" ).resizable({
                    maxHeight: 500,
                    maxWidth: 500,
                    minHeight: 50,
                    minWidth: 20,
                    aspectRatio: true,
                    handles: "se",
                    distance: 50
                });
            }
        });
}
```

In the comment you can see where the problem is, sometimes it appends without a problem, sometimes not no matter if I clear the cache or not, but it ALWAYS append this stuff when I call `add` twice with exactly the same stuff. What can I do here to make it always work? I can't preload the png image before AJAX because the png image is getting created in convert.php

I hope my problem is kind of understandable and sorry for my bad english :D

Comment: I haven't gone through the whole code, as it is quite lengthy and hard to test. But it sounds like a problem with the image not loading? Have you thought to try waitForImages - https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, did you see the update? When I call $( ".drag" ).draggable({ and $( ".resize" ).draggable({ with like 1 second timeout then it works fine, it executes after the image is fully loaded, but how could I do it just when AJAX success is just 100% finished? Which means append etc is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
        var image = new Image();

        $(image).on('load', function(){

            $('#baukasten').append(
                '<div class=\"drag\" id="' + currentid + '" style=\"display: inline-block; cursor: all-scroll; z-index: ' + currentzindex + '; position: absolute; border: 1px solid #000000;\" onmousedown=\"mach(this);\"><img src=\"png/' + produktid + '.png" class=\"resize\"><img src=\"close.png\" class=\"close\" style=\"width: 16px; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px;\" data-raus=\"' + currentid + '\" onclick=\"raus(this);\"><img src=\"resize.png\" class=\"res\" style=\"width: 18px; position: absolute; bottom: 5px; right: 5px;\" data-res="' + currentid + '"><\/div>'
            );

            $( ".drag" ).draggable({
                containment: "#grenze"
            });

            $( ".resize" ).resizable({
                maxHeight: 500,
                maxWidth: 500,
                minHeight: 50,
                minWidth: 20,
                aspectRatio: true,
                handles: "se",
                distance: 50
            });

            $('#lightbox').hide();
        });

        image.src = "http://www.bla.com/test/png/" + produktid + ".png";

    }
});
```

even if the chance is 0.001% someone will ever need it xD